# Is there a `grep`-like utility to match strings instead of lines?

Tags: linux, grep, regex

I'm using grep to extract lines that match a regular expression. How to get only the matches and not the whole line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can supply grep the `-o` option. Like such:

```
grep -o pattern file
```

(*Hint*: The mnemonic I use for this is: **o**mit everything except match)